# I can't access the response variable in this get function in that dart, what could be it?

Tags: flutter, dart

```dart
 Future<Response> getRequest(String baseUrl) async {
    Response response;
    try {
      response = await _dio.get(baseUrl);
      print('I can\'t print this line');
    } on DioError catch (e) {
      print(e.message);

      throw Exception(e.message);
    }
    return response;
  }
```

Comment: Can you include your code-snippet instead of code-image?  Are you using null-safety version?

Comment: Any answers for this?

Comment: Is it throwing exception? If yes include it!!

Comment: None, no exceptions

Comment: It will return null if it failed on try bloc,

Comment: Please post the actual error message. This code snippet would make my linter jump from a bridge, but if yours is fine with it, we need to know what *else* you may have problems with.

Comment: There is no error but it's not returning any thing